# html5 mustache get the index of article and compare the value

Tags: javascript, arrays, html, mustache

I have a mustache file, and I am iterating over the array:

```
var data = {
        sales: [
            {
                name: "Jim Frost",
                region: "USA East",
                phone: "212-555-1212",
                email: "jfrost@acme-travel.com"
            },
            {
                name: "Jan Smith",
                region: "USA West",
                phone: "310-555-1212",
            },
            {
                name: "Fred Wesley",
                phone: "608-555-1212",
                email: "fwesley@acme-travel.com"
            },
            {
                name: "Lisa Moore",
                region: "USA South",
                phone: "315-555-1212",
                email: "lmoore@acme-travel.com"
            },
            {
                name: "Jim Dio",
                phone: "+ 44 022-555-1212",
                email: "jdio@acme-travel.com"
            },
            {
                name: "Charles Watts",
                region: "Spain",
                email: "cwatts@acme-travel.com"
            },
            {
                name: "Bert Cooper",
                region: "Italy",
                email: "bcooper@acme-travel.com"
            }
        ]
};
```

here is the markup:

```
<div>
    <section>
        {{#data.sales}}
        <article class="items">
            <div class="region">{{{region}}}</div>
        </article>
        {{/data.sales}}
    </section>
</div>
```

I want to add some special style (like, bold font, color etc) ONLY if the region is `USA East`. 
how can i detect inside this inherent loop in the article element if `{{{region}}` has a specific value? Given that the comparison will be made against a value that i get from backend, say {{myValue}}, which is manually set to *USA East* in the backend.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a function in the `data` which will return the correct class depending on the region value. Something like

```
data['regionClass'] = function(){
  if ( this['region'] == 'USA East' ) {
    return "strong green";
  }else{
    return "";
  }
}
```

And then in the Mustache you can do: `<div class="region {{regionClass}}">{{{region}}}</div>`